# How would you dispose of this SPSite object?

Tags: 2010, development

I'm doing a simple overloading of a function and I create a SPSite object when I'm calling the second function. I'm not sure of how to dispose of it in this scenario.

```
public static string GetConfigValue(string name, string webURL)
{
   return GetConfigValue(configName, new SPSite(webURL).RootWeb);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this :

```
public static string GetConfigValue(string configName, string webURL)
{
   string returnVal = null;

   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webURL)) {
      returnVal = GetConfigValue(configName, site.RootWeb);
   }

   return returnVal;
}
```

That assumes that you have another overloaded version of GetConfigValue(string, SPWeb).

You should be aware that instantiating SPSite and SPWeb objects in utility functions is a horribly inefficient way to code and will perform poorly under stress.